# Java split by white spaces with condition

Tags: java, split

I want to split string by white spaces. However if words are enclosed with quotation marks, then treat them as a single word.

For example `Word to split`. I will get `word`,`to`,`split`.

but if
`"word to" split` i should get `"word to"`, `split`. quotation mark remains.

Comment: You might need a parser to handle every edge case here (not my downvote).

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen here. You need to specify all valid inputs and edge cases before we start writing regexes. Also, show us what you've tried :)

Comment: I would probably split and check if the current entry in the resulting array is a quotation mark in which case I will simply look for the closing mark, otherwise you already know what to do. The regex will produce a much cleaner solution though.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly - There are better ways of doing this using *lookaheads* and *lookbehinds*. But unless the OP specifies corner cases and different kinds of inputs, its difficult to write a correct regex

Comment: @TheLostMind♦ Wow `lookaheads` and `lookbehinds`, that's probably the first time I hear about those, it's good to learn something new!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want??

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class TmpTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String regex = "\".*?\"|\\b\\w+\\b";
        final String string = "\"word to\" split i should get \"word to2\", split.";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Qa071/2)

Comment: Thank you. What will be the regex if quotation is changed to `$` for example `$word to$ split` i should get `word to`,`split`

Comment: Then the regex should be `final String regex = "@.*?@|\\b\\w+\\b";`

Comment: Thanks. Last question. If it is a dollar sign?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with regex but I got it `\$.*?\$|\b\w+\b`. :)

Comment: Don't edit your comment if the asked question (in comment) already answered. i see you already edit your first comment and in your first comment you asked regex for `@` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
String str = "\"word to\" split";

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    list.add(m.group(1)); // Add .replace("\"", "") to remove surrounding quotes.


System.out.println(list);
```